# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08103: object no longer exists in java

Tags: java, jdbc

When i am  generating a report, I get "java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08103: object no longer exists".Code below

```
con = commonDB.getConnection();
st = con.createStatement();
rs = st.executeQuery(selQuery);
while (rs.next()) {
      epfForm3Bean = new AaiEpfform3Bean();
      .......
       .......
         form3DataList.add(epfForm3Bean);
}
```

We have generated this report many times;but didn't get this exception.Today we generated this report i got exception.please help me

Comment: The code is not sufficient to tell what is going on. What is the `selQuery` you are running?

Comment: You've already tried asking Google about the error code?  http://www.google.dk/search?q=ORA-08103

Comment: You, as a developer, should pay attention to exception. Just telling "java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08103: object no longer exists" is absolutely not helpful. Always post error stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to given inputs it seems you are referring to an object that does not exist.

for instance it may a table which does not exists.

*1. you can change the object*

or

*2.you can create a new object with same name.*

hope it helps ,give more details to help you better

[check this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora08103.php)